# Service Worker on Create React App doesn't load video on safari

Tags: reactjs, video, safari, create-react-app, service-worker

I am trying to get my PWA working on Ipad and Safari but I'm messing with an issue with Safari and the `Service worker` that is automatically generated by "create React App".

I saw that is a common problem from what can read from this articles: [one](https://github.com/philnash/philna.sh/blob/ba798a2d5d8364fc7c1dae1819cbd8ef103c8b67/sw.js#L50-L94), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087208/pwa-cached-video-will-not-play-in-mobile-safari-11-4) and especially [three](https://philna.sh/blog/2018/10/23/service-workers-beware-safaris-range-request/).

Honestly I'm a noob and I don't know how to implement my service worker to be functioning implementing the `returnRangeRequest` as mentioned from the third link.

Here's my service worker.

```js
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
  // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
  window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
  // 127.0.0.0/8 are considered localhost for IPv4.
  window.location.hostname.match(
    /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
  )
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
            'worker. 
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (event === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
        window.skipWaiting();
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                'tabs for this page are closed.
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl, {
      headers: {
        'Service-Worker': 'script'
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then(registration => {
        registration.unregister();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  }
}
```

I know it's not the correct way, but i'm asking if somebody con support me on this.